# Issues with updating LongListSelector after reassigning the source to a deserialized JSON Collection

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I've been trying to get started in Windows Phone/C# programming and started a small project that is supposed to pull some database data off my server and display everything accordingly on my phone. I've been using the Channel 9 guides and Google/StackOverflow as a guidance and that worked great so far, but now I ran into an issue I can't fully comprehend and need help with.

I have a PlanModel class that is supposed to be kinda like the MainViewModelClass and looks like this:

```
public class PlanModel
{
    public PlanModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<PlanData>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PlanData> Items { get; set; }
    public bool IsDataLoaded { get; set; }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        LoadPlanData();

        IsDataLoaded = true;
    }

    public async Task LoadPlanData()
    {
        // URL censored, the JSON is deserialized correctly, checked with debug
        Uri ApiAddress = new Uri("http://example.com");

        WebClient Client = new WebClient();
        Client.DownloadStringCompleted += Client_DownloadStringCompleted;
        Client.DownloadStringAsync(ApiAddress);
    }

    void Client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ApiResult;

        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            ApiResult = e.Result;
            Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<PlanData>>(ApiResult);       
        }
    }
}
```

My App.xaml.cs is linked up and working fine, I just modified the version that exists when you create a new project. I think that I have to implement the INotifyChanged property somehow or something along those lines, but I tried a dozen combinations (List, ObservableCollections with OnCollectionChanged and OnPropertyChanged) and nothing actually updated my main page view during runtime when the async data was loaded.

I would really appreciate if anyone could give me an example with a small explanation on how to properly make the view update - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get the Task stuff for the moment, you don't need it for this simple example.

try this: (I have implemented the basic INotifyPropertyChanged stuff for you to look at.

```
     public class PlanModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PlanModel()
    {
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PlanData> Items { get; set; }
    public bool IsDataLoaded { get; set; }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<PlanData>();
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Items");

        LoadPlanData();

    }

    public void LoadPlanData()
    {
        // URL censored, the JSON is deserialized correctly, checked with debug
        Uri apiAddress = new Uri("http://example.com");


        // Web client is disposable, so wrap in a using statment to ensure clean up.
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += Client_DownloadStringCompleted;
        client.DownloadStringAsync(apiAddress);
    }

    void Client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ApiResult;

        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            ApiResult = e.Result;
            var itemsFromService = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<PlanData>>(ApiResult);

            foreach (var planDataItem in itemsFromService)
            {
                this.Items.Add(planDataItem);
            }

            IsDataLoaded = true;
        }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: WebClient doesn't seem to be disposable anymore - I already tried to implement that, but it didn't work out because WebClient can't be converted to IDisposable implicitly. IntelliSense is also not showing Dispose, so either I have a very stupid mistake somewhere or it can't be disposed anymore.
But other than that, thank you for your help! You helped me finally understand these Updated handlers.

Comment: WebClient is disposable dude. it has to be given its operation

Comment: In [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444851/should-webclient-instances-be-reused-in-silverlight) in the comment section of the second answer the issue is discussed to an extent. I'm compiling it for WinPhone 8. The using statement just gives me an error because it's not disposable.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to find my way around that issue alone, but thanks for all the help nonetheless. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the list to the new list of objects you should add the list to your observable list.

Like:

```
foreach(var item in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<PlanData>>(ApiResult))
{
     Items.Add(item);
}
```

If you just set the list to a new list the observables will not be triggered.

If you needs to clear your list before adding new use:

```
Items.Clear();
```

/Michael